# How to ignore a "Level" in R?

Tags: r

Not sure how to do the following. Please refer to the picture in the link below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx79x.png

I have some blank spaces, and they are the missing values. I do not want this level to be read. I want R to ignore this level. I want to write a regression so that this empty category is not part of the model.

The data was read from a csv file. The variable is "I", "II"...."IV", but there is an extra "" factor because of missing data. I want R to ignore this factor. My question is how?

Comment: Please provide additional information. We have no clue what you are doing (maybe you read data from a file?...) and thus cannot help you. Hint: Have a look at the `subset()` function, maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
df <- data.frame(letters=letters[1:5], numbers=c(1,2,3,"",5)) # my data frame

#    letters numbers
# 1       a       1
# 2       b       2
# 3       c       3
# 4       d        
# 5       e       5

levels(df$numbers)

# ""  "1" "2" "3" "5"


subdf <- subset(df, numbers != "") # data subset

subdf$numbers <- factor(subdf$numbers)

levels(subdf$numbers)

# "1" "2" "3" "5"
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `""` data to missing:

```
# generate sample data
df <- data.frame(x = sample(c("","I","II","III"),100, replace = T), stringsAsFactors = T)
```

option 1

```
df[df$x=="",'x'] <- NA
```

option 2

```
df$x <- factor(ifelse(df$x == "",NA,as.character(df$x)))
```